# XSLT: Parent stylesheet imports child stylesheet, but child cannot see parent's variable

Tags: xslt, variables, import, include

I have a parent stylesheet defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:import href="external/webcommon/WebappTransform.xsl" />
    <xsl:variable name="webAppFinalName">rf</xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

The imported stylesheet `WebappTransform.xsl` contains some inline CSS includes within certain templates:

```
@import url("/{$webAppFinalName}/external/webcommon/css/print.css");
```

The transformation occurs within a Java servlet filter and I cannot see the output HTML exactly, however it is clear from the final results that the variable has not been correctly inserted.

If I manually insert the variable and try with the full XSL then all is well.

Could someone please explain what's wrong here? Consulting a number of online resources suggests this approach should work.

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import any "xsl:import element is only allowed as a top-level element. The xsl:import element children must precede all other element children of an xsl:stylesheet element" so your snippet with `xsl:variable` preceding `xsl:import` has the wrong order, I would expect the XSLT processor to raise an error message.

Comment: That's actually a paste error on my part - the order is correct in my code. I've amended my OP though, ty.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
@import url("/{$webAppFinalName}/external/webcommon/css/print.css");
```

is just a plain string. No variable substitution will take place here during the transformation.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('@import url(&quot;/', $webAppFinalName, 
                     '/external/webcommon/css/print.css&quot;);')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you mzjn, I'll try this at work first thing tomorrow and reply then :)

Comment: It didn't, and I'm unsure whether it's because of how we use the transformation (in a servlet filter, applied via javax transform) or because it's incorrect in itself. I'm sure you're sure it's correct (!) but I'll be reattempting this next week after a few more project changes, so intend to respond then.